# Email obfuscation/munging recent research

Tags: email, obfuscation

Does anyone know of any recent (past year or two) research into email obfuscation/munging?

All I can find are tests done five to ten years ago.

I'm trying to decide whether it's something still worth doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obfuscation is a technique used to, obfuscate, or make less obvious, something.
From a security perspective, obfuscation can make it more difficult or time consuming for a human attacker to understand whatever it is they are looking at. (It could also be a method of security through obscurity, by hiding things, as an example.) Most of the time people view obfuscation as a method of making source code less readable, and any number of obfuscators exist to serve the purpose. Likewise, a number of deobfuscators exist that will reverse the obfuscation process to make the code or what not more readable.  Obfuscating an E-mail address serves no real purpose against programmable "spam-bots" that can pretty much read the E-mail address and deobfuscate it on the fly. You can use it if you like, but I wouldn't expect any real protection from a computerized threat like that.